# Explanation of async-await code block for a newbie. Why is user.password_hash null?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I new to node.js, express, and async/await functions, promises, callbacks, etc. Most relevant parts of what I am asking about are toward the bottom of the code I have posted.

The code does what I need it to, but I have a question about why `user.password_hash` has a set value (as intended) in the debug I have after the comment that says

`// next line works`,

but has a value of null in the line after the comment

`// but this says value of the password_hash is null?`.

The latter debug statement comes after the code that sets the value of user.password_hash, so why wouldn't it have the hash value too?

Apparently, I do not understand what is going on with async/await functions. Is there a way to have the value of user.password_hash accessible outside the block it is in? Kindly make the explanation super simple, as intended for an inexperienced programmer like me. Thanks!

```
const { request } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const moment = require('moment');
const db = require('../db');
const authMiddleware = require('../middleware/auth');
const debug = require('debug')('app:routes:account');

// creating instance of router.
const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(express.json());

router.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let user = { username: null, email: null, password: null, password_hash: null };
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.email = req.body.email;

    user.password = req.body.password;
    const password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;
    const emailRegExp = /^([A-Za-z0-9_.+-])+\@[A-Za-z0-9_+-]+[\.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    debug(
      `username = ${user.username}, email = ${user.email}, password = ${user.password}, passwordConfirm = ${password_confirm}`
    );
    const data = {
      title: 'Register for an account',
      isPost: true,
      passwordsMatch: false,
      isValid: true,
    };
    if (!user.username) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.usernameError = 'username is required';
    }
    if (!user.email) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.emailError = 'email is required';
    } else if (!emailRegExp.test(user.email)) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.emailError = 'email must be 8 characters or longer.';
    } else {
    }
    debug(`user.username ${user.username}`);
    if (!user.password) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.passwordError = 'Password missing.';
    } else if (user.password.length < 8) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.passwordError = 'password not long enough';
    } else if (user.password != password_confirm) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.password_confirmError = 'Passwords must match.';
    } else {
    }
    if (data.isValid) {
      (async () => {
        try {
          const saltRounds = 10;
          const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds);
          debug(`password to hash ${user.password} and hash ${hash}`);
          user.password_hash = hash;
          // next line works.
          debug(`in async, password_hash ${user.password_hash}`);
          const result = await db.registerUser(user);
          debug(`BIG RESULTS: ${result}`);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      })();
      // but this says value of the password_hash is null? 
      debug(`***user is  ${user.username}, email ${user.email}, hash ${user.password_hash}`);
    }

    res.render('account/register', { title: 'Errors!', data });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

UPDATE, I am trying this code, now it won't update the database....why? And I am trying to pass data on to the res.render for success in the update, but that was never working either. Why does it only work with async await? How can I access the data put in the database with async-await there?

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let user = { username: null, email: null, password: null, password_hash: null };
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.email = req.body.email;

    user.password = req.body.password;
    const password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;
    const emailRegExp = /^([A-Za-z0-9_.+-])+\@[A-Za-z0-9_+-]+[\.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    debug(
      `username = ${user.username}, email = ${user.email}, password = ${user.password}, passwordConfirm = ${password_confirm}`
    );
    const data = {
      title: 'Register for an account',
      isPost: true,
      passwordsMatch: false,
      isValid: true,
    };
    if (!user.username) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.usernameError = 'username is required';
    }
    if (!user.email) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.emailError = 'email is required';
    } else if (!emailRegExp.test(user.email)) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.emailError = 'email must be 8 characters or longer.';
    } else {
    }
    debug(`user.username ${user.username}`);
    debug(
      `username = ${user.username}, email = ${user.email}, password = ${user.password}, passwordConfirm = ${password_confirm}`
    );
    if (!user.password) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.passwordError = 'Password missing.';
    } else if (user.password.length < 8) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.passwordError = 'password not long enough';
    } else if (user.password != password_confirm) {
      data.isValid = false;
      data.password_confirmError = 'Passwords must match.';
    } else {
      ///
      // res.render('account/registration-success');
      // but this says value of the password_hash is null?
      // debug(`***user is  ${user.username}, email ${user.email}, hash ${user.password_hash}`);
    }
    if (!data.isValid) {
      res.render('account/register', { title: 'Errors!', data });
    } else {
        try {
          const data = {};
          const saltRounds = 10;
          const hash = bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds);
          debug(`password to hash ${user.password} and hash ${hash}`);
          user.password_hash = hash;
          data.username = user.username;
          // next line works.
          debug(`in async, password_hash ${user.password_hash}`);
          const result =  db.registerUser(user);
          // debug(`BIG RESULTS: ${JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)}`);
          debug(`BIG RESULTS: ${result}`);
          res.render('account/registration-success', data);
          // const payload = {
          //   user_id: user.user_id,
          //   username: user.username,
          //   email: user.email,
          //   registration_time: user.registration_time,
          //   last_login_time: moment(),
          // };
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
    }

    ///
    // if (data.isValid) {
    //   const saltRounds = 10;
    //   bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    //     if (err) {
    //       console.error(err);
    //     } else {
    //       user.password_hash = hash;
    //       debug(`password to hash ${user.password} and hash ${hash}`);
    //       const result = db.registerUser(user);
    //       debug(`result is ${result}`);
    //       res.render('account/registration-success', result);
    //     }
    //   });
    // }

    // res.render('account/register', { title: 'Errors!', data });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

SOLUTION --- THIS IS THE CODE THAT FINALLY WORKED, cleaned up a bit.. I suppose what got it working was putting `await` in front of each part. Thanks to jsfriend00 for his patience with me.

```
 if (!data.isValid) {
      res.render('account/register', { title: 'Errors!', data });
    } else {
      user.registration_time = moment();
      user.password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
      await db.registerUser(user);
      await res.render('account/registration-success', { user });
    }
```

Comment: Your immediately invoked async function that starts with this `(async () => {...})` returns  a PROMISE and it has not finished it's internal execution until that promise is resolved.  There is no free lunch with `async/await`.  The caller still has to pay attention to the returned promise if they want to use a result from inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what you mean by it not having finished it's internal execution. What line of code could I write here in this code? And...aren't I paying attention the returned promise with the "user.password_hash - hash" line?

Comment: So you understand that an `async` function returns a promise IMMEDIATELY upon the first `await` inside the async function?  And while the internals of the function are sitting at the `await`, the rest of the code AFTER the function call continues to run.  So, you're examining `user.username` BEFORE the value has yet been set inside the `async` function.  You're trying to cheat asynchronous code with `(async () => {...})` and that type of cheating doesn't work.

Comment: FYI, it appears you don't need the `(async () => {...})` construct at all.  Just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct you're using:

```
(async () => {

      console.log("0");
      await xxx()
      // more code
      console.log("1");

})();
console.log("2");
```

Does not work the way you apparently think it does.  The above code will show in the console as:

```
0
2
1
```

The moment an `async` function hits its first `await`, it immediately returns a promise and execution continues after the function call.  Sometime later, the promise that you're using `await` on resolves and then the internals of the function finish and then that previously returned promise is resolved.

It appears that in your particular function here, you can just remove the `(async () => {...})()` construct entirely.  You're already inside an `async` function so you can already use `await` and then the rest of your code WILL wait for the `await`.

Comment: Thanks, this does help my understanding, but then my code breaks if I take anything out except the  ``(async () => {...})`` part. 


And I did try doing this synchronously, taking out all the async & await. However, the db.registerUser(user) doesn't work then without the await in front of it, which I don't understand why it would matter. If I do use await then I can't render my page with the data that's put in the database.

Comment: I just posted an update that is totally broke now. Not sure where I am going wrong, and don't understand when it is a good idea to use async-await or just go synchronous. Is there no way to access the data put in the database with my original code, like a .then or something?

Comment: @PaulW - Why did you take the `await` out on the `bcrypt.hash()`?  You need it.  Same with `db.registerUser()`

Comment: @PaulW - And, put the `async` back in `router.post('/register', async (req, res, next)`.  ALL I wanted you to remove was the `(async () => {...})()` wrapper you had around that code block.  Leave everything else as it was.

Comment: I took it out cuz I don't know what I am doing...I don't know what right looks like yet because it hasn't worked for me yet. I am trying right now. My db.registerUser doesn't update, despite having all the data there from my debug messages. Anyway, I am debugging this now with that you told me above. I'll post back.

Comment: where would I put the ``const result = db.registerUser(user);`` or  ``const result = await db.registerUser(user);``?

If I use several awaits, do they fire in order?

Comment: @PaulW - Leave your code EXACTLY how you originally had it.  Just remove the `(async () => {...})()` wrapper.  All the places you had an `await` on an asynchronous operation that returns a promise, you still need those.  Yes, multiple `await` statements will run in order.  The second will wait for the first and so on.  It's only when you return from an async function that things don't wait.  You want your code to be ALL in one `async` function so you can successfully run things sequentially.

Comment: @PaulW - Also, please do some more learning about how promises and async/await work so you aren't just guessing how to code things like this.

Comment: I am really trying to grasp this, I really am. The take-away from this is that multiple awaits run in their sequence. I somehow had the wrong idea that only one could be an await. How do I give you credit for help me, just click the check mark next to your answer? The comments are what got me on the right path. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @PaulW - Yes, just click the checkmark next to my answer.